# CSS style being dynamically set is being overridden

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have few `<asp:LinkButton>`'s in my website menu bar. The menu bar and these buttons have Css set. What I am looking for is to highlight the button corresponding to which ever page is active.

I could apply a new Css class dynamically to my `Linkbuttons`(*rendered as anchor tags by the browser*) but the newly applied CSS is overridden by the existing class. I have tried analyzing any mistake there but no luck. This is my code-

A part of HTML-

```
<ul class="navigation">
   <li>
       <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtn_about" runat="server" OnClick="lbtn_about_Click">About Us</asp:LinkButton>
   </li>
```

Existing css-

```
 ul.navigation li a
  {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color: #838383;
    height: 24px;
  }
```

Css class to be set dynamically-

```
.activeLink
  {
    color: #588500;
  }
```

In my page loads I am doing this-

```
LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)Page.Master.Master.FindControl("lbtn_about");
lb.CssClass = "activeLink";
```

HTML rendered in browser-

```
<a id="ctl00_ctl00_lbtn_about" class="activeLink" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$lbtn_about','')">About Us</a>
```

Its clear that the class is set, but the `activeLink` css is overridden by the `ul.navigation li a`. Suggestions please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `ul.navigation li a` is more specific than `.activeLink`.

If you think about a point system an element say `ul` has 1 point, a class say `navigation` has 10. Therefore the `ul.navigation li a` has at least 11 points on just the `ul.navigation` vs the `activeLink` of 10.

A good [detailed article on css specificity](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html)!

http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html">

As for a solution you just need to reference your `.activeLink` with more specificity, be it with an `#id` or a `ul.navigation li a.activeLink`.

Go forth and may the css be with you!

Comment: That's interesting. I dint know about the Css specificity. Thanks for the link. Let me have a look at it and your solution :)